# Is ‘then’ of ‘now and then’ past or future?

Tags: phrases, time

*Then* is commonly used for things happened in both the past and future.

In the common phrase *now and then*, is *then* in the past or the future? Could anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn’t have any temporally anchored reference.  If you combine it with a past tense verb, it means “on randomly distributed past occasions”:

> John helped out (every) now and then

Combine with a future modal, it means “on randomly distributed future occasions”:

> John will help out (every) now and then

It is also acceptable with the present tense, in which case it refers to randomly distributed events before and after now:

> John helps out (every) now and then

Comment: Now I see how English natives grasp a meaning of it. Thanks a lot

Comment: +1 And *now* also lacks a true temproal reference. It does not mean "at the time the narrator is speaking" because it can refer to fully completed acts or those totally in the future. "John will be expected to help out *now and then*.

Comment: @bib.  Indeed: if _now_ had a specific (context-dependent) reference, it would be impossible to quantify over it with _every_.  suzukimilanpaak has drawn attention to fascinating construction.

Answer (score 4):

*Now and then* or *now and again* is a phrase and means *from time to time*. So it could refer to past, present or future.